# How To Grep Information and Results to be in Columns(Linux)

Tags: linux, grep

I have the below data to process such that each each block of data that starts with `<SUBBEGIN` and ends with `<SUBEND` will be processed.

```
<SUBBEGIN
    AARB:28E5A4ERR
    SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234810128
    GBRUL:0
    GBRDL:0
    SUBSCRIPTION:5093201&733D8E01CA&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160729121530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    SUBSCRIPTION:5233555&733D8E01CA&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160730091530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    QUOTA:5093201&733D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    QUOTA:5233555&633D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    ONLINESTATUS:2
    LATEST_ONLINE_TIME:20170330191209
    CREATETYPE:0
    MAXOFFLINEDAYS:0
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
    BBRB:28E5A4ETT
    SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234825528
    GBRUL:0
    GBRDL:0
    SUBSCRIPTION:5093333&733D8E01CA&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160729121530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    QUOTA:5093264&733D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    ONLINESTATUS:2
    LATEST_ONLINE_TIME:20170330191209
    CREATETYPE:0
    MAXOFFLINEDAYS:0
<SUBEND
<SUBBEGIN
    CCRB:28E5A4ESS
    SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234993527
    GBRUL:0
    GBRDL:0
    SUBSCRIPTION:5093264&733D8E01MB&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160729121530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    SUBSCRIPTION:9093201&733D8E01CA&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160729121530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    SUBSCRIPTION:6598777&733D8E01CA&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&20160730091530&FFFFFFFFFFFFFF&2&1&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&255&0&255&256&FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF&0&0&128&1
    QUOTA:5093264&733D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    QUOTA:9093201&733D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    QUOTA:6598777&633D8201D10D270D&1&1&0&1&20171121043000&20171221043000&0&255&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0
    ONLINESTATUS:2
    LATEST_ONLINE_TIME:20170330191209
    CREATETYPE:0
    MAXOFFLINEDAYS:0
<SUBEND
```

I have used this linux command already:
`grep -e SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER -e SUBSCRIPTION -e QUOTA`
But I got result in rows, whereas I need it to be in columns as below(please copy the below expectation to ultredit program to see the full length):

```
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234810128 SUBSCRIPTION:5093201 SUBSCRIPTION:5233555                        QUOTA:5093201 QUOTA:5233555
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234825528 SUBSCRIPTION:5093333                                             QUOTA:5093264
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234993527 SUBSCRIPTION:5093264 SUBSCRIPTION:9093201 SUBSCRIPTION:6598777   QUOTA:5093264 QUOTA:9093201 QUOTA:6598777
```

Kindly help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'&' '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"")} /SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/{id=$1} /SUBSCRIPTION/{s=s","$1} /QUOTA/{q=q","$1} /SUBEND/{print id,s,q; id=""; s=""; q=""}' data | column -t | tr , ' '
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234810128   SUBSCRIPTION:5093201 SUBSCRIPTION:5233555                        QUOTA:5093201 QUOTA:5233555
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234825528   SUBSCRIPTION:5093333                                             QUOTA:5093264
SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234993527   SUBSCRIPTION:5093264 SUBSCRIPTION:9093201 SUBSCRIPTION:6598777   QUOTA:5093264 QUOTA:9093201 QUOTA:6598777
```

#### How it works

- `-F'&'`

  This tells awk to use `&` as the field separator.
- `sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"")`

  This removes all leading blanks from each line.
- `/SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/{id=$1}`

  This saves the  SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER information in variable `id`.
- `/SUBSCRIPTION/{s=s","$1}`

  This saves all SUBSCRIPTION information in comma-separated format in the variable `s`.
- `/QUOTA/{q=q","$1}`

  This saves all QUOTA information in comma-separated format in the variable `q`.
- `/SUBEND/{print id,s,q; id=""; s=""; q=""}`

  Everytime we reach SUBEND, we print out a line of data and reset all variables
- `column -t`

  This pretty-formats the output data into columns.
- `tr , ' '`

  This removes the commas from the output.

#### Update

According to your comment, the name of the file you are using is `UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt` and you want to append the results in the file `Result.txt`.  In that case, run:

```
awk -F'&' '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"")} /SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/{id=$1} /SUBSCRIPTION/{s=s","$1} /QUOTA/{q=q","$1} /SUBEND/{print id,s,q; id=""; s=""; q=""}' UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt | column -t | tr , ' ' >>Result.txt
```

Note that the `cat` command is not needed here.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response. However, I uploaded a file named UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt in which the command you provided is to be executed, but got the following error:

Comment: thanks for your response. However, I uploaded a file named UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt in which the command you provided is to be executed, but got the following error:    bill@vaslab:~/UPCC$ cat UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt | awk -F'&' '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]+/,"")} /SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER/{id=$1} /SUBSCRIPTION/{s=s","$1} /QUOTA/{q=q","$1} /SUBEND/{print id,s,q; id=""; s=""; q=""}' data | column -t | tr , ' '>>Result.txt
awk: cannot open data (No such file or directory)

Comment: @OluseyiVictor OK.  I see the problem.  If that is the name of your file, please run the command that I added to the `Update` section at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

using **awk**

```
$ awk -F"&" '/^<SUBBEGIN$/{a=1} a && /^[[:blank:]]+(SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|SUBSCRIPTION|QUOTA)/{l=l OFS $1} a && /^<SUBEND$/ {print l; a=l=""}' f1
     SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234810128     SUBSCRIPTION:5093201     SUBSCRIPTION:5233555     QUOTA:5093201     QUOTA:5233555
     SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234825528     SUBSCRIPTION:5093333     QUOTA:5093264
     SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER:234993527     SUBSCRIPTION:5093264     SUBSCRIPTION:9093201     SUBSCRIPTION:6598777     QUOTA:5093264     QUOTA:9093201     QUOTA:6598777
```

`/^<SUBBEGIN$/{a=1}` : If record is `<SUBBEGIN` then set flag `a` which marks the beginning of the block

`a && /^[[:blank:]]+(SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|SUBSCRIPTION|QUOTA)/{l=l OFS $1}` : If `a` is set and record matches one of the words you specified in your original question then append the record upto first field to variable `l` (Note : `FS="&"`)

`a && /^<SUBEND$/ {print l; a=l=""}'` : If `a` is set and block end reached then reset all variables.

Comment: thanks for your response. However the output file which I got after executing the below command was blank:                              awk -F"&" '/^<SUBBEGIN$/{a=1} a && /^[[:blank:]]+(SUBSCRIBERIDENTIFIER|SUBSCRIPTION|QUOTA)/{l=l OFS $1} a && /^<SUBEND$/ {print l; a=l=""}' UPCC_5_20171124144300_0_huabiao1_601.txt>>VertGrp.txt

Comment: try after removing `$` from this command. It could be that your input files may have spaces after `SUBBEGIN` and `SUBEND`.  Point to note is, it does work on the input you provided here.